# Adding button next to tabs in TabWidget

Tags: python, pyside6

I am looking to add a button for a new tab right next to the open tabs (much like a browser).
However, none of the default Layouts support stacking items on top of each other and **displaying both**. Can anyone give some pointers on how I can accomplish this? A grid layout at best puts them side by side, but puts the button to the far side.

Minimum runnable code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
        QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout
    )

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.container = QWidget()  # Controls container widget.
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout()   # Controls container layout. Might need to be Horizontal with Veritical for some.

        # Add stuff here before

        # See https://pythonbasics.org/pyqt-tabwidget/ on tab widgets
        self.tabs_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        label1 = QLabel("Widget in Tab 1.")
        # have classes for each page
        self.tabs.addTab(label1, "First")
        self.tabs.addTab(label1, "Second")
        self.tabs_layout.addWidget(self.tabs, 1, 0)
        # Add new tab button
        self.new_tab_button = QPushButton("+")
        self.tabs_layout.addWidget(self.new_tab_button, 0, 1)
        self.controlsLayout.addLayout(self.tabs_layout)
```

I know this is accomplishable because apps like Konsole (which uses Qt behind the scenes) has this functionality.

This has absolute positioning, which I might need
https://www.loekvandenouweland.com/content/pyside6-widget-absolute-position.html

Comment: Adding a layout for the tab widget and the button is not effective, as you should know the tab bar geometries, all tab contents, etc. The only way to do so is by implementing a QTabWidget and related QTabBar subclasses.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the reply, I am trying to test the code linked. However, my imports can not find, PM_TabBarTabHSpace or pyqtSignal despite them being in the pyside6 documentation. Tips? I am new to pyside6

Comment: i changed pyqtsignal to a regular signal. Looking at the PM_TabBarTabHSpace now. also, PM_DefaultFrameWidth is not found in QStyle

Comment: PySide6 and PyQt6 changed the way enums are used, which have become actual python enums instead of basic integers: they are not direct members of their class anymore, and the namespace of their flags must always be used now: `PM_TabBarTabHSpace` is part of `QStyle.PixelMetric`, so the full syntax is `QStyle.PixelMetric.PM_TabBarTabHSpace` (add the `QtWidgets.` prefix if you imported the submodule instead of individual classes). Also, that answer refers to PyQt, which uses the `pyqt` prefix for signal/slot/property names; in PySide they are just `Signal`, `Slot` and `Property` respectively.

Comment: I have your code semi-working now except the plus sign does not open new tabs. playing with it now.

Comment: The button cannot create arbitrary tabs, and for obvious reasons: what should be the content of that tab? You have to connect to the `addClicked` of the tab widget and eventually call `addTab()` with the required widget for the new tab. Please accept the duplicate proposal.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. Something as simple as ```    s.addClicked.connect(s.addTab(label, 'Test'))
``` does not add any tabs, and after the second click, the + disappears and I get an error about ```AttributeError: 'ShrinkTabBar' object has no attribute '_tabHint'````

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't work because because it's *wrong*. Signal connections accept *callables*, but there you're directly calling the function. That should be, at least, `s.addClicked.connect(lambda: s.addTab(label, 'Test'))`. Please do more research about signals, slots and their connections. I cannot test with PySide6 right now, so I suggest you to carefully read the code and figure out what it does, so that you can try to fix any issue that may be related to the different binding or Qt version (also run the code in a terminal or prompt so that you always get the *full* traceback).

Comment: my bad, I had it as `lambda.'  I'll have to continue to play around with the code.

Comment: I hacked away at your code, and I got it. I do not know if it is designed properly but it works.

Comment: I had to set _tabHInt and another variable to 0 in the constructor. This is because I wanted to have empty tabs on creation that then could have widgets added by choice. Please see https://file.io/EcCz5fweaQoJ. @musicamante   tab '4' is the starting tab

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, would be to not use a QTabWidget but a QTabBar combined with a QStackedwidget (or QStackedLayout).
The tabbar is now a separate widget that you can put in a horizontal layout with a button and a stretch to the right of it.
You'd have to set up the connections between the tabbar and the stackedwidget manually, but on the whole it may be easier than creating a custom QTabWidget.